# How to remove href tag from CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have following CDATA inside xml document:

```
<![CDATA[ <p xmlns="">Refer to the below: <br/>
</p>
<table xmlns:abc="http://google.com pic.xsd" cellspacing="1" class="c" type="custom" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr xmlns="">            
            <th style="text-align: left">Basic offers...</th>
        </tr>
        <tr xmlns="">
            <td style="text-align: left">Faster network</td>
            <td style="text-align: left">
            <ul>                
                <li>Session</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr xmlns="">
            <td style="text-align: left">capabilities</td>
            <td style="text-align: left">
            <ul>                
                <li>Navigation,</li>
                <li>message, and</li>
                <li>contacts</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr xmlns="">
            <td style="text-align: left">Data</td>
            <td style="text-align: left">
            <p>Here visit google for more info <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><font color="#0033cc">www.google.com</font></a>.</p>
            <p>Remove this href tag <a href="/abc/def/{T}/t/1" target="_blank">Information</a> remove the tag.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p xmlns=""><br/>
</p>
  ]]>
```

I want to some how scan for href="/abc/def   and remove the href tag which starts with abc/def. In above example remove the href tag and just leave "Information" text inside the tag. CDATA can have more than one href tags with "abc/def... in it.
I am using C# for this application. Can someone please help me and tell me how this can be done? Should i use regex or is there a way to do it with xml itself?

This is the regex i am trying:

```
"<a href=\"/abc/def/.*></a>"
```

I want to keep inner text of the a href tag just remove the tags. But above regex is not working.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - yes i am using XmlDocument in c# to load the xml document. Than using node to extract CDATA into string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("a")
    .Where(n => n.Attributes.Any(a => a.Name == "href" && a.Value.StartsWith("/abc/def")))
    .ToArray();

foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node,true);
}

var newHtml = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: Hi do i have to download this HtmlAgilityPack? I have never used this before?

Comment: Yes I gave the link in the answer. It is one of the *must-have* tools for every developer.

Comment: Even better than parsing as XML, this prevents exceptions if the HTML is not XML-wellformed. Note to LB: the OP mentioned that it can contain multiple a-elements with the given properties.

Comment: Amazing amazing answer. Cant give more than plus one on this otherwise will give all my points on this answer. Thanks @L.B

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this task. The task itself is quite simple: to select nodes by using xpath, and then remove them. The thing left is to get the result HTML:

> It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web"
>   HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed
>   HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml,
>   but for HTML documents (or streams).

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(xml);

var anchors = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(@href, '/abc/def')]");
foreach (var anchor in anchors.ToList())
    anchor.Remove();

var result= doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

This will get you exactly you want.

**EDIT:**

If you want to remove the `href` attribute only, change this line `anchor.Remove()` to this one `anchor.Attributes["href"].Remove();`

Comment: wow this thing is amazing. Only problem with above code is it is removing the text of a href also which is "Information" in above example how can i avoid that?

Comment: @NoviceMe Alex's code removes the node, you want to only remove the attribute. Either select the attribute and remove it, or have a look at LB's answer, it shows you how-to (you can combine both techniques: LB uses LINQ, where Alex uses XPath).

Comment: @NoviceMe, updated my answer with the code to remove the `href` attribute only instead of removing the *whole* node.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML is well formed XML (which at a glance it looks like) you can load the text of the cdata node into a new XML document, modify the XML as appropriate, and then replace the text of the original cdata node with the XML text of your modified document.

Since cdata is by definition not parsed in the original XML document, that is why you will need a secondary one.

Comment: +1 by far better than any regular expression, which are always a poor approach to dealing with XML/HTML. If it is not valid XML, you can choose to use HTMLTidy or TagSoup to make it valid.

Comment: @Abel this doesn't remove the need to use a regular expression at all, it just makes it necessary to use it many times over every single node content. The answer also does nothing to help the user solve the actual problem they're facing.

Comment: @Alain: regular expressions should be used for matching text, not structured documents. Yes, for matching the _text value_ in the attribute `href`, you could use a regex (though other approaches can be used in this scenario). There's nothing wrong with regexes per se, just don't use them with structured data and try to replace what's already there. `ab c` and `&#x61;b c` and `ab&nbsp;c` can all be equal text (the last requires a dtd), it's impossible to do that with regexes. After XML parsing, all this becomes just `ab c`.

Comment: @Abel this definitely removes the need for reg ex.  A single xpath statement does the node selection. I'd never recommend reg ex if a good parser (xml or html in this case) is available

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I'm not recommending running this Regex on the entire XML string - since most agree this is bad. The following regular expression can and should be run on the individual nodes of the document during proper traversal.** The solution was posted as a single regex replacement on the entire xmlString since that was what the user requested and they were having trouble adapting the Regular expression statement to their particular situation - I wrote the code character by character to match how they were intending to use it as closely as possible.

---

To strip all `href` tags where the url starts with `/abc/def/`, you're better off using a regular expression:

```
result = Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"<a href=\"/abc/def/.*>(.*)</a>", "$1");
```

---

**Followup to comments below**

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx):

> Within a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a specified regular expression with a specified replacement string.

This replacement will happen on all instances, not just the first one. If the rest aren't working, it's because there's something different about them that doesn't match the regular expression.

For instance, if there are extra spaces between the a and href in some cases, or the target field is specified before the href field, you would need to use a someone less specific replacement:

```
result = Regex.Replace(str, @"<a.*href=\"/OST/OSTdisplay/.*>(.*)</a>", "$1");
```

Comment: Quick edit - forgot the syntax for grouping is `(group)` and referenced by `$1` (Unlike in Visual Studio which annoyingly uses a completely different syntax: `{group}` and /1 :p)

Comment: i dont want to remove all the href tags only ones which start with /abc/def . Can you please tell me what the regex for that be?

Comment: Oh. Well yeah then just change it to `@"<a href=\"/abc/def/.*>(.*)</a>"`

Comment: Regex's are pretty simple as long as you keep in mind [the characters that need to be escaped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx).

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. It should only remove href tag not the text inside it. Above expression is removing the text too.

Comment: If you use "$1" as the replace string, it should not be replacing the text inside it, just the surrounding `<a href> tags`. Can you verify that you are using the correct replace string?

Comment: i tried this: <a href=""/abc/def/.*></a> this is not working.

Comment: Please post your complete attempt in your question above, and make sure it's exactly the code that my solution recommends. What you just pasted is not a well formed `Regex.Replace` expression.

Comment: The Regex you posted is wrong, it does not contain the grouped expression `(.*)` which is the whole thing that makes it work.

Comment: Use EXACTLY this: `Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"<a href=\"/OST/OSTdisplay/.*>(.*)</a>", "$1");`

Comment: this works if there is only one abc/def. If there are more than one abc/def tags it does not work?

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx): `Within a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a specified regular expression with a specified replacement string.` This replacement will happen on all instances, not just the first one. If the rest aren't working, it's because there's something different about them that doesn't match the regular expression.

Comment: For instance, if there are extra spaces between the `a` and `href` in some cases, or the `target` field is specified before the `href` field, you would need to use a someone less specific replacement: `Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"<a.*href=\"/OST/OSTdisplay/.*>(.*)</a>", "$1");`